# The message for empty list for ng-repeat always flash?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The following code from an ionic project supposes to display message "No record" when the `events` is empty. However, the message always show for half a second and then disappear even when `events` is not empty? How to get rid of the flash?

```
<a ng-repeat="event in events">
  ....
</a>
<div ng-hide="events.length"> <!-- <div ng-show="!events.length"> behaves the same -->
  <div ....>
  No record.
  </div>
<div>
```

**Update:**
A testable plunker is created https://plnkr.co/edit/lchTKN6C8niAsALquHoF?p=preview, you can see the red message still flash even the list is not empty?

Comment: `ng-cloak` is designed to be used with css to hide elements while angular bootrstraps or does initial compile..see docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-cloak` along with `ng-hide/ng-show`

```
<div ng-hide="events.length" ng-cloak> <!-- <div ng-show="!events.length"> behaves the same -->
  No record.
<div>
```

> The **ngCloak** directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) for ng-cloak

**UPDATE:**

Since the `$scope.events` array got initialized with an empty value before the return of the service completes. The convention is to use the `$promise` object to get access to the result of the deferred task when it completes.

```
var allEvents = EventService.query({ category: "Music" });

allEvents.$promise.then(function (response) {
    $scope.events = response;
});
```

[Demo of working plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/7r0ZuXbXx6UX2VZDFspn?p=preview)

Comment: Just tried in emulator and it seems not resolve the problem?

Comment: Could be two things, first - change it to `ng-show="events.length == 0" ng-cloak` , secondly do you have `$scope.events = [ ]` defined somewhere in controller before events are loaded.

Comment: I did both changes but still no luck. The controller is `.controller('AAACtrl', function ($scope, EventService) {
    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.events = EventService.query({ category: "AAA" });
})` now.

Comment: i meant **remove** this `$scope.events = [];` if you have this defined in controller.

Comment: No it was not there but still had the issue.

Comment: Create a plunker to replicate the issue.

Comment: The plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/lchTKN6C8niAsALquHoF?p=preview is created. The `Shouldn't show!!!!!` flash right before the content is shown.

Comment: Thanks it works. So `ng-cloak` is not necessary? I found it works even when it's removed?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, if you are expecting the response to be null at some point, let `ng-cloak` stay as an attribute.