# How to avoid flicker effect in views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two views: In first view I fetch some data from the database and show a list. In the second view I have a detail page for a list item.
I can pass the clicked list item object to my detail page, but there is a short flicker effekt.
For example I show different type of info text based on the type of clicked item.

```
<span ng-show="item.type == 1">Type 1</span>
<span ng-show="item.type == 2">Type 2</span>
```

The problem is I can see for a very short time both texts -> flicker effect. 
Now I figured out there is ng-cloak, but it not really helps me if I use it in this way:

```
    <div ng-cloak>
     <span ng-show="item.type == 1">Type 1</span>
     <span ng-show="item.type == 2">Type 2</span>
    </div>
```

How can I avoid the flicker effect?

EDIT: In my controller I listen to the view enter event and only there I assign variables to my scope:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    $scope.item.type = item.type;
});
```

Maybe this is the issue. I guess this event waits until the view change animation finished. Is there a way to make it work this way?

Comment: probably because the response is delayed and items is initialized. I answered the same question here :  See the plunker in question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506812/the-message-for-empty-list-for-ng-repeat-always-flash/